# $_POST print the same value again and again

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am able to pass the multiple values to ajax page using post method, but when I'm printing the values in ajax page it prints the values again and again. I'm stuck and couldn't understand whats happening.

```
<script>
//sending values through Jquery
var department1;
var location1;
var sub_department1;
    $(function(){
        $('.item_filter').click(function(){
            department1 = multiple_values('department');
            location1  = multiple_values('location');
            alert(location1);
            sub_department1  = multiple_values('sub_department');
            $.ajax({
                url:"search-jobs.php",
                type:'post',
                data:{department12:department1,location12:location1,sub_department12:sub_department1},
                success:function(result){alert(result);
                    $('.corporate-jobs').html(result);
                },
            });
        });
    });
function multiple_values(inputclass){
    var val = new Array();
    $("."+inputclass+":checked").each(function() {
        val.push($(this).val());
    });
    return val;
}
</script>


<?php
 //printing values in Ajax page    
//Fetch data from corporate page
$locations = $_POST['location12'];    
print_r($locations);die();    
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Deoghar
    [1] => Dhanbad
)
Array
(
    [0] => Deoghar
    [1] => Dhanbad
)
Array
(
    [0] => Deoghar
    [1] => Dhanbad
)
Array
(
    [0] => Deoghar
    [1] => Dhanbad
)
Array
(
    [0] => Deoghar
    [1] => Dhanbad
)
Array
(
    [0] => Deoghar
    [1] => Dhanbad
)
```

Comment: is this output comes only in single request?

Comment: Why did you remove the PHP code that does the output and the output-example?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? What does **exactly** happen?

Comment: @ Nico Haase I've tried everthing, after printing the post on ajax page, it prints the same values again and again and I'm unable to figure out what's happening.

Comment: @piyush I didn't get you

Comment: Please help me out on this, i've to do this by the end of the day

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've added the output and php code

Comment: What do you get in the console if you do `console.log(location1);` right before you're making the Ajax request? Is this code triggered several times? What does your HTML look like, where you fetch the values from? There's nothing in that code that would make it print multiple times. It must be the values or that the code get's executed multiple times.

Comment: alert(location1) prints only one location and if multiple locations are selected then it alerts the multiple locations, no issue with that, but after the AJAX request print_r($_POST[locations]) prints the same output again and gain

Comment: <p><input name="" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $departmentArray['department']; ?>" class="item_filter department">&nbsp;&nbsp;15102100 ( 14 )<?php echo $departmentArray['department']; ?></p> and this is the checkbox

Comment: If possible just send a test mail to anindya12.it@gmail.com, I'll send you the whole code

Answer (score 0):

```
var CheckedVal = [];
$("."+inputclass+":checked").each(function() {
    CheckedVal.push($(this).val());
});
return CheckedVal;
```

Try This Code...